# How I can use iMacros to edit an html?

Tags: javascript, html, imacros

Using iMacros, I need to change this html command

```
<button class="btn btn--primary btn--large" disabled="" type="button" aria-label="Search" id="w0-find-product-search-bar-search-button" data-w-onclick="beforeSearch|w0-find-product-search-bar" style="outline: 1px solid blue;">Get started</button>
```

to

```
<button class="btn btn--primary btn--large" type="button" aria-label="Search" id="w0-find-product-search-bar-search-button" data-w-onclick="beforeSearch|w0-find-product-search-bar" style="outline: 1px solid blue;">Get started</button>
```

I mean to remove `disabled=""` from the script.

Ty

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.querySelector("#w0-find-product-search-bar-search-button").removeAttribute("disabled");}
```

Comment: Must work in 'iMacros for Firefox' v. **8.9.7** or lower and 'iMacros for Chrome'.